# How to get exception information when using async methods in SSH.NET?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ssh, ssh.net

I am using asynchronous methods of SSH.NET C# API to manage SFTP operations. If I specify invalid remote path in BeginDownloadFile or BeginUploadFile then the operation fails and my asyncCallback is called immediately with 0 transferred bytes count. I want to get hold of exception information but it doesn't seem to be passed. I installed an error handler on SFTP connection (ErrorOccurred) but it never gets called. Any idea of how exception can be trapped when using async methods of SSH.NET?

Comment: do you use .net 5 ? the exception handeling has been improved / simplefied

Comment: I am using .NET 4.5.2.

Comment: I meant C# 6 http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2015/01/csharp-6-await-statement.html but for .net 4.5 there is duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-method

Comment: I've found the error: I was not using EndDownloadFile in the callback handler. Once I added it there, it threw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

I've found the error: I was not using EndDownloadFile in the callback handler. Once I added it there, it threw an exception.