# What is the reason behind CS1998 "method lacks await operators"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

The C# compiler generates a CS1998 warning when an `async` method lacks any `await` operators.

*What are the reasons behind the warning?*

I know that `async` introduces overhead in the method by adding a statemachine and exception handling.

Is the primary reason for the warning *performance*?
Or is the reason to notify me that I might have forgotten an `await` somewhere?

Maybe someone from the language design team can shed some light on this one... :)

(Please: do not post answers that say 'you can remove `async` to make the warning go away'. I want to know the reasons and decisions behind the warning, not ways to work around it.)

Comment: There's not much point to a method being `async` if it doesn't have any `await`s in it.

Comment: I'm not a language designer, but an obvious incorrect assumption from new programmers would be that a method marked `async` somehow executes, well, asynchronously. This is manifestly untrue if there are no `await` operators anywhere. "This does not do what you expect and there is a better way of writing whatever you are trying to achieve" is an obvious candidate situation for a compiler warning.

Comment: @juharr, well it changes exception behaviour for the caller when the callee is `async`.

Comment: @juharr there is one reason: `Task<TResult>` doesn’t have covariance, so if you return something using `Task.FromResult()`, you might have to manually specify the generic type instead of letting type inference (if your method returns a superclass of the value you pass to `Task.FromResult()`). And if you have to implement a method signature such as `Task MyMethod()`, it is much cleaner to write `async Task MyMethod() { DoSomething(); }` than `Task MyMethod() { DoSomething(); return Task.CompletedTask; }`

Comment: @JeroenMostert isn't it just a problem of "new programmers" that they don't understand how those thing work? And why exactly the "other way of doing things" is better?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What are the reasons behind the warning?

Simply put, an `async` method that does not use `await` is almost certainly wrong. Not *always* wrong, or this would be an error. But *almost* always wrong, hence the warning.

An incredibly common async-newbie mistake is to assume `async` means "make this method asynchronous". This is commonly paired with the assumption that "asynchronous" means "run on a background thread", but sometimes it's just an assumption of "magic".

Thus, the warning explicitly points out that the code will run *synchronously*.

I have also found this warning helpful when refactoring my own code - sometimes I end up with an `async` method that should be changed to a synchronous method, and this warning points that out.

It's true that `async` without `await` could be useful to reduce code if you have non-trivial (i.e., possibly exception-generating) synchronous code and you need to implement an asynchronous method signature. In that case, you can use `async` to avoid a half-dozen lines of `TaskCompletionSource<T>` and `try`/`catch` code. But this is an extremely small use case; the vast majority of the time, the warning is helpful.

Comment: The exception handling case you mention is exactly the scenario I am currently facing. I was thinking about ignoring the warning, but was unsure if this is a good idea. With your answer I feel like suppressing the warning for certain cases is OK. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I’d say that the “extremely small use case” of being able to avoid `return Task.CompletedTask;` or the scenario of needing to specify `TResult` manually because type inference chooses a subclass of the method’s return type when using `Task<SuperClass> MyMethodAsync() => Task.FromResult(subClassValue);` (compilation error, cannot cast `Task<SubClass>` to `Task<SuperClass>`) outweighs any benefit of this warning. I am disabling this warning via `<PropertyGroup><NoWarn>CS1998</NoWarn></PropertyGroup>` myself…

Comment: I just ran into a tricky error where I returned null where a Task should be returned. No problem in an async method but really bad otherwise. I have all Async signatures (with virtual methods) but not all methods in the base class need it. To avoid the warning I lived with that mix. Until now. I'm going to ditch that warning. I know now what I'm doing.

Comment: Why on Earth does the compiler try to "explain" something to "async-newbie"? I think that it should be simply checking the code and compiling it. That's it.
There is also a phrase "Simply put, an async method that does not use await is almost certainly wrong" with no explanation. Just a statement without even an example. What are those "wrong" cases?
I still didn't get why this warning is useful.

Comment: @VictorYarema: The best error messages are ones that are actionable. Thus, compilers in recent years have attempted to make their error messages much better instead of making devs google them. This was not always the case; in the late '90s I actually built up a document of C++ errors along with "this is what this means". Regarding `async` without `await`, the reason it's usually wrong is that the primary purpose of the `async` keyword **is** to enable the `await` keyword: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/11/11/asynchrony-in-c-5-part-six-whither-async/