# Is awaiting methods from synchronous sources with await Task.Run(() => good practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that has the async keyword with a task. This method returns a string that comes from `JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(t);` The thing is none of the assignments in the body of the method are awaitable.I get the warning   CS-1998. That says you shouldnt use async for synchronous methods which makes complete sense. But then it adds that you can use  `await Task.Run(() => {` . So is it good practice to do this?

```
public async Task<object> GenerateMyUserJwtToken(string email, IdentityUser user)
//code that isnt awaitable
        {
var u = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            });

            return  u;
}
```

edit: I did not ask what the error was I asked if it was a good idea to Implement await Task.Run(() on an async method signature that has no await assignments. I also asked that another async method is awaiting this in the another method here is the code

//awaiting method:

```
public async Task<object> LoginAsync(LoginDto model)
        {

                return await GenerateMyUserJwtToken(model.Email, appUser);

        }



//controller:
    [HttpPost("login")]
            public async Task<object> Login([FromBody] LoginDto model)
            {


      var logMeIn = await new AuthUserService().LoginAsync(model);
                return logMeIn; //returns token


            }
```

My Question is is this async all the way or does the task.Run stop that process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the reason behind CS1998 "method lacks await operators"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594737/what-is-the-reason-behind-cs1998-method-lacks-await-operators)

Comment: Consider Task.FromResult<T>

Comment: I keep reading in blogs not to use that. Link:   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: If you want to propagate your asynchronous code, but some of your methods are synchronous, then using `Task.FromResult` is good. It will run synchronously, but will allow you to propagate async further down the application.. [This](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) post can clarify when to use `await Task.Run`. Basically you want to let `UI` thread handle running async code for you, e.g. from a handler.

Comment: Hey thanks guys you answered my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Task.Run` just to make something sync is generally a bad practice but it cannot be stated generally.

If the sync method to execute may take for a long time, then it *can be* a solution. Please note that `Task.Run` will assign the task to a pool thread and it is not always desirable. It is a common misunderstanding that async methods always use or should use threads somewhere at the end of the async-await chain. However, async-await has [nothing to do with threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), it is about asynchronicity (chaining deferred tasks) and creating threads is just one option to create awaitable tasks.

So what are the options?

1. The method to call is fast and never blocks the caller for long time (>100ms or so): do not use async at all. In this case `Task<T>.FromResult(result)` is a tempting solution but is highly discouraged because it is misleading for the caller. Use it only in unit tests or if you are forced to implement an async method of an interface you cannot change.
2. The method execution takes for a long time because it is CPU bound: now you can use a thread. But I typically would not use pool threads for long lasting tasks as it can cause nasty side effects if the thread pool is out of threads. Use `await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyLongRunningTask(), cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);` instead, which creates a brand new thread instead of bothering the pool.
3. The method execution takes for a long time because it is IO bound (eg. sending/receiving packets via a hardware): Use `TaskCompletitionSource<T>`, add a hook to the whatever completition event of the device (eg. OS hook or IRQ notification) and from that set the result of the completition source and return its task.

Comment: Great answer exactly what I asked. Thank you.