# Does adding a Task<T> to the return of a method make it run in a thread?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I am struggling to find any solid information online, but lets pretend I have a method like below:

```
public int DoSomething()
{
    // some sync logic that takes a while
    return someResult
}
```

So lets assume it is a method that is completely sync and currently will block the thread the caller is on for 100ms. So then lets say I wanted to create a version that would not block that thread while it executes, is it as simple as just doing:

```
public Task<int> DoSomethingAsync()
{
    // some sync logic that takes a while
    return Task.FromResult(someResult)
}
```

As I know `Task.Run` will cause code to be executed within a thread, but does .net basically interpret any method with a `Task/<T>` return type to be something that should be non blocking?

(I am hesitant to use the word async as it has mixed meanings in .net, but as shown above there is no await use here)

Comment: `Task.FromResult` will run synchronously on the same thread. If you want to force task to be run by one of ThreadPool threads you can use `Task.Yield()` at the beginning, but here, there is no use for that. I would keep `Task.FromResult` only to allow for easy propagation of async code later on.

Comment: Just a comment, a Task is not neccessarily a new thread. It might be a new thread, it  also might run on the current current thread. The point is it will be run at some point and it will be completed and you dont need to care.

Comment: May I ask how you came to this conclusion? Did you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for Task.FromResult?

Comment: In other languages the same concept as .NET Task is named "Promise", which is I think somewhat less confusing: promise is, well, promise to provide a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is awaiting methods from synchronous sources with await Task.Run(() => good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839498/is-awaiting-methods-from-synchronous-sources-with-await-task-run-good-prac)

Comment: @taffer Not really, this question is specifically wondering if the `Task` return type will automatically indicate that the contents should be non-blocking, and as the answer explains the return type doesn't enforce anything, it just *allows* the content to be run in a thread internally if needed. Similar sort of domain between questions though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. All that changing the return type does is... change the return type.

You're changing your promise from "when I return I will give you an `int`" to "when I return, I will give you something that will eventually provide an `int`" (with the caveat that the value may, in fact, already be available).

*How* your method comes up with the `Task` is entirely an *internal* implementation detail that is a concern for your method. In your current changed implementation, it does it by running entirely on the same thread from which it was called and then just stuffing the result into a `Task` at the end - to no real benefit.

If you had added the `async` keyword and left the `return someResult;` line you'd have been given more clues about this by the compiler:

> This `async` method lacks '`await`' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using ...

Comment: All good info! I am hesitant to wrap everything in `Task.Run` but looks like that is ultimately the simplest way to make the sync stuff happen in a non blocking way.

Comment: @Grofit - don't do that internally to a method that is naturally sync - leave it up to the caller of this method to do the `Task.Run` as required. See [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) for more details. (It also has a companion piece about doing things the other way around)

Comment: Yeah, its just a faff for the consumer, as mentioned in the article if you have resource heavy things like `Stream` `WriteAsync` and `ReadAsync` it is nice if the consumer can have a way to have a non blocking way to call the method, in this context it would be some heavy serialization which touches on reflection, so all of it will be executed sync under the hood, but can take a while.