# What different between Task.Run(Foo) and FooAsync()?

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, threadpool

In fact, I'm asking about What the different between **Use a thread run a block method** AND **Direct run a unblock/asynchronous method**?

Such as [GetResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponse) / [GetResponseAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync), [ExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader) / [BeginExecuteReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader) etc.

On the surface, neither blockades the program, but what's the difference in principle? I think this actually involves a real understanding of multithreading and asynchrony.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer:** `Task.Run` will assign the method to a pool thread whereas an async method just has to return a `Task`, but apart from that it does whatever it wants.

**A bit detailed answer:**

Without any specific example it is impossible to tell what will happen in an async method. It may or may not use a thread inside or it can 'cheat' and block the caller the same way as a regular method returning something by `Task.FromResult(myResult)` in the end.

Actually `Task.Run` has overloads with `Func<Task>` and `Func<Task<TResult>>` parameters as well so if you know that an async method cheats (or though it doesn't use a thread you want to force it for some well-founded reason), then you can wrap even already async methods in `Task.Run` calls.

**As for the concrete examples:**

- `Task.Run(() => GetResponse(...))` returns immediately an uncompleted `Task` and schedules `GetResponse` to be executed on a pool thread. Once the thread finishes, the task will be completed.
- `GetResponseAsync(...)` returns immediately an uncompleted task that will be completed once the response is received on the underlying socket. No pool threads this time.
- `Task.Run(() => ExecuteReader(...))`: same as for the first point
- `BeginExecuteReader`: Now this is an interesting one. As this uses the .NET 1.0 `IAsyncResult` solution we may think it just calls a `Delegate.BeginInvoke` for `ExecuteReader`, which would be the trivial solution and would also end up using a pool thread. But if you investigate [BeginExecuteReaderInternal](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,f5568fc166847821) you can see that it also uses tasks internally. It must have been refactored since tasks were introduced in .NET 4.0.

Btw, you can await also `IAsyncResult` methods by `TaskFactory`:

```
await Task.Factory.FromAsync(BeginExecuteReader(...));
```

This will not create any additional threads (on top of the ones created by the `Begin...` method, if any) just turns the `IAsyncResult` into an awaitable `Task` in a  convenient way.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I don't want to talk abount APM/TAP libs or codes, please focus on theories of threads and asynchronous, I shouldn't mention Task, It's my fault.Do you mean `Foo` will hold a thread/CPU time util return, but `FooAsync` may not? So from the point of saving computing resources, is the `FooAsync()` better than `ThreadRun(Foo)`?

Comment: This is what you cannot tell in general. Even a non-async method can start something in the background and return immediately. If there is a pair of async and non-async version of a method, then _you can have conventional assumptions_. But it can happen that a poorly implemented async method just returns the non-async method by `FromResult` (blocking) or wraps the blocking method into a `Task.Run` call. Which can help to make a UI responsive but in the end consumes more resources (scheduling a task, managing threads, etc). See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48839498/5114784)