# Why is my async method finishing before the next line in the caller method is executed?

Tags: c#, async-await

Consider the following method:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            // Begin timing.
            stopwatch.Start();

            Task task =  dosomething(stopwatch);
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for async to finish {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("After wait {0}",stopwatch.Elapsed);


            // Stop timing.
            stopwatch.Stop();

            // Write result.
        }

        public static async Task dosomething(Stopwatch stopwatch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started async", stopwatch.Elapsed);
            await dos();
            Console.WriteLine("Ended async", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }

        public static async Task dos()  
        {
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected the output to be in this order:

> Started Async
>
> Waiting for async to finish
>
> Ended async
>
> After wait

But instead I get the following output

> Started async
>
> Ended async
>
> Waiting for async to finish 00:00:06.0990283
>
> After wait 00:00:06.0992659

I thought while you await the completion of a method, control returns to the caller. Hence "waiting for async to finish" should have been called before "ended async".

Comment: Don't ignore warnings. The compiler should have alerted you that `dos` doesn't `await` anything and will therefore complete synchronously. Use `await Task.Delay`, not `Thread.Sleep`. `async` does *not* mean "run this in the background for me", it means "allow me to use `await` syntax to write asynchronous code as if it were synchronous". You still need to supply the actual asynchronous code.

Comment: Microsoft has some very well-written articles on asynchronous programming that are worth the read. Start here: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/).

Comment: I was running this on dotnetfiddle.com Didnt see any warnings there >.<

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Thread.Sleep` is **not** asynchronous. Therefore, the thread will be blocked and your code will be executed synchronously. If you exchange your `Thread.Sleep` with `await Task.Delay`, you'll get your expected output.

For more information about the warning that the compiler should have emitted (CS1998), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594737/what-is-the-reason-behind-cs1998-method-lacks-await-operators). Quoting Stephen Cleary:

> An incredibly common async-newbie mistake is to assume async means "make this method asynchronous". This is commonly paired with the assumption that "asynchronous" means "run on a background thread", but sometimes it's just an assumption of "magic".
>
> Thus, the warning explicitly points out that the code will run
>   synchronously.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in other answers Task.Delay() works but also, you do not need to create a task object reference and then call it. I just called .Wait() on doSomething and it worked for me.

Here is my solution

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        // Begin timing.
        stopwatch.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for async to finish {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        dosomething(stopwatch).Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("After wait {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        // Stop timing.
        stopwatch.Stop();

        // Write result.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static async Task dosomething(Stopwatch stopwatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started async", stopwatch.Elapsed);
        await Task.Delay(6000);
        Console.WriteLine("Ended async", stopwatch.Elapsed);
    }
```