# .NET TPL: Why is delegate being ran like it was executed with blocking wait call?

Tags: c#, .net, task, task-parallel-library

When I'm trying to run Task.Run method with delegate which runs another task without blocking call it's being ran like my task was exectued with Wait blocking call?

Here is an example:
I'm trying to run this:

```
namespace Console_App_Sandbox
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token), cts.Token);
                //Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm getting an exception.

But in case If I'd ran it not via Task.Run I'd not get an exception because other not awaited/waited thread's cancelled task exception won't be caught in the current thread:

```
namespace Console_App_Sandbox
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
            try
            {
                //await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token), cts.Token);
                Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

Adding the blocking wait call will get us to the exception caughting:

```
namespace Console_App_Sandbox
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
            try
            {
                //await Task.Run(() => Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token), cts.Token);
                Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I've added async keyword to the delegate I'm passing into the Task.Run method exception won't be caught:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Console_App_Sandbox
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(2000);
            try
            {
                await Task.Run( async () => Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token), cts.Token);
                //Task.Delay(3000, cts.Token).Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

How does it work? It seems like when delegate is not async blocking wait call will be added to tasks which were ran.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your question rather than providing image links.

Comment: Post the code as *text* in the question. Images can't be copied, compiled or tested

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've edited my post, screenshots were replaced with code!

Comment: You don't await `Task.Delay` so execution won't stop at it. The application will exit before the CTS expires. `Task.Run(()=>Task.Delay())` just returns the inner task so the code in the first snippet is essentially `await Task.Delay()` plus some overhead

Comment: `Task.Delay` doesn't freeze the current thread. Essentially, it's a custom task whose completion state is triggered by a timer.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, yes, question is about why am I getting an exception even if I don't wait while task will be finished or cancelled? In the same situation when I run the task in the main thread and not waiting until it will be finished I'll not get an exception.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, oh, it seems I've understand why it's occured, thank you very much!

Comment: But I still don't understand why only adding async keyword changes the behaviour: actually async keyword only changes the semantics of a method, it doesn't make any action, it only makes the await keyword to be an operator.

Comment: `async` doesn't change execution, it's just syntactic sugar that tells the compiler to emit the code needed for awaiting. It's `await` that actually awaits a task. You can't use `await` without `async`

Comment: Yes, but only adding async modificator shouldn't change the behaviour of the method without adding await because only await make an action

Comment: I understand that async doesn't change execution, but if you will run the first and the last code snippets I've provided in the post, you'll see that only adding of async keyword will change the behaviour. Why does it happen?

Comment: I bet that you are getting some compilation warnings when you ran the 2nd and 4th code snippet. Aren't these warnings educational? Aren't they guide you towards the right direction?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, actually I've only messages about unused parameter args and new operator simplification, there's no any other warnings or messages.

Comment: And it's not a question about what is the right direction, I just want to understand how does it work, I know that it isn't a right way of working with async code.

Comment: The warnings I had in mind are the [CS1998](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594737/what-is-the-reason-behind-cs1998-method-lacks-await-operators) and the [CS4014](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014). You should be getting the first one in the 4th code snippet. The second doesn't apply to any of the four snippets though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, sorry, I've not noticed that I've passed func instead of action and I thought that there's no an returned value. Thank you very much, now I could understand what's going on.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've noticed that I've passed Func instead of Action and I couldn't understand that I've returned an inner task from the Task.Run method. Now it's pretty logical that exception is caught. Thanks much for all who helped my to find out the reason of such behaviour, especially for Panagiotis Canavos!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).