# Catching an exception in an async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await

I am trying to get more familiar with async/await programming and exception handling.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   TestAsyncException();
}

private static async void TestAsyncException()
{
    try
    {
        var result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething());
        //do something with the result
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}

private static int DoSomething()
{
    throw new Exception("Exception was thrown!");
}
```

I am expecting the `Exception` to be handled gracefully but instead the code execution stops and I get

> An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in .. but was not
>   handled in user code.

But then when I continue executing the code the `Exception` actually gets caught (and the message is displayed to the `Console`).

How am I supposed to catch the `Exception` without breaking the execution of my code?

Comment: If this is your real code, it's not a good example. `TestAsyncException` returns the control to `Main` while `await`ing, so `Main` returns too and the process is terminated. This interfers with the exceptions and it's hard to predict how they get handled.

Comment: I believe that the try catch needs to also be around the main thread running the async method as the exception gets thrown to the main thread (I might be wrong)

Comment: maybe this answer helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-method

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre The exception is caught before it gets to that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your exception is handled.  I believe you are seeing the code stop execution and display the error because you have `Break When Thrown` on for exceptions.  Check your Exception Window (`Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings`).

When you use a return type of `void` on an `async` method, you lack the ability to get any sort of information back from the method - it's fire and forget.  Except in specific situations, this is bad practice.  Always have your async methods return a `Task` or `Task<T>`:

```
private static async Task TestAsyncException()
```

Now, your main method can listen to the task:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestAsyncException().Wait(); // or whatever you want to do with the task
    Console.Read();
}
```

Normally, you could use `await` to unwrap the task here, but that's not allowed in the application entry point.