# Return the results of Tasks - including the exceptions?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

The following code run `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, `M4` in parallel. Each method may raise exceptions. The method should return the results of the four async methods - either the int returned by methods or the Exceptions.

```
async Task<string> RunAll()
{
    int m1result, m2result, m3result, m4result;
    try
    {
        var m1task = M1();
        var m2task = M2();
        var m3task = M3();
        var m4task = M4();
        // await Task.WhenAll(new Task<int>[] { m1task, m2task, m3task, m4task });
        m1result = await m1task;
        m2result = await m2task;
        m3result = await m3task;
        m4result = await m4task;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // need to return the ex of the failed task. How?
    }
    // How to implement M1HasException, M2HasException, ... in the following lines?
    var m1msg = M1HasException ? M1ExceptionMessage : m1result.ToString();
    var m2msg = M2HasException ? M2ExceptionMessage : m2result.ToString();
    var m3msg = M3HasException ? M3ExceptionMessage : m3result.ToString();
    var m4msg = M4HasException ? M4ExceptionMessage : m4result.ToString();
    return $"M1: {m1msg}, M2: {m2msg}, M3: {m3msg}, M4: {m4msg}";
}
```

How to capture the individual exceptions of the failed task?

For example, if only M2 threw an exception,

```
"M1: 1, M2: Excpetion...., M3: 3, M4: 4"
```

Comment: `Task.WhenAll`  ?

Comment: I tried `Task.WhenAll()`, it seems not helping to get which task got the exception. The question was updated.

Comment: I recommend looking into this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5383408/5312245

Comment: A [mcve] would be great here.

Answer (score 1):

Each task has a Status and and Exception property.

You may want to see if it has faulted:

```
myTask.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted
```

Or if it has excepted:

```
if (myTask.Exception != null)
```

You can use `ContinueWhenAll` to run all the tasks and then check the status.

[See the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: The problem is as soon as, for example, `M2` got an exception, `M3` and `M4` stopped being invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Could you wrap each `await` in `try-catch` block and capture the exception message if any, seems feasible...

```
var results = new List<string>();

try { results.Add(await t1); } catch { results.Add("Exception"); };
try { results.Add(await t2); } catch { results.Add("Exception"); };
try { results.Add(await t3); } catch { results.Add("Exception"); };

return string.Join("|", results);
```

if you want to use `WhenAll` you could `await` for it and ignore exceptions and then do the same exercise as shown above to retrieve individual task results...

```
try { await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2, t3); } catch { };
//                                      ^^^^^^^^^
// then same as ^ above
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers/comments pointed out, one possible approach is by using `ContinueWith` or `ContinueWhenAll`. This is a clever trick because `Task` has the `Exception` property:

> Gets the AggregateException that caused the Task to end prematurely.
>   If the Task completed successfully or has not yet thrown any
>   exceptions, this will return null.

Using `ContinueWith` whether a task completes successfully or not, it will be passed as the argument to the delegate function. From there you can check if an exception was thrown.

```
Task<string> GetStringedResult<T>(Task<T> initialTask)
{
    return initialTask.ContinueWith(t => {
        return t.Exception?.InnerException.Message ?? t.Result.ToString();
    });
}

async Task<string> RunAll()
{
    string m1result, m2result, m3result, m4result;

    var m1task = GetStringedResult(M1());
    var m2task = GetStringedResult(M2());
    var m3task = GetStringedResult(M3());
    var m4task = GetStringedResult(M4());

    m1result = await m1task;
    m2result = await m2task;
    m3result = await m3task;
    m4result = await m4task;

    return $"M1: {m1result}, M2: {m2result}, M3: {m3result}, M4: {m4result}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the tasks inside a `WaitAll` and catch the `AggregateException` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.7.2)),

```
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(new[] { task1, task2 }, token);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
        //Do what ever you want with the ex.
}
```