# C#: calling [async] method without [await] will not catch its thrown exception?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await, throw

I'm having this code snippet:

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task ProcessAsync(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("call function");
        if (s == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("throw");
            throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("print");
        await Task.Run(() => Console.WriteLine(s));
        Console.WriteLine("end");
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessAsync(null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

It runs and prints:

```
call function
throw
```

Ok, and exception is thrown, but the main function's try/catch is not able to catch the exception, if I remove the try/catch, main doesn't report unhandled exception either. This is very weird, I googled and it says there's trap in [await] but doesn't explain how and why.

So my question, why here the exception is not caught, what's the pitfalls of using await?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, you `Run` the `Task` but you do it in *fire and forget* manner: you don't `await` for the execution results; so if an exception is thrown it will be within the task only. Others there is a problem: in which thread (and when) it should be re-thrown?

Comment: Change your `Main()` method to `public static async Task Main(string[] args)` and `await` your call to `ProcessAsync(null);`

Comment: See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-void-method) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) for more information

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/exception-handling-task-parallel-library?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Within an `async` method, any exceptions are caught by the runtime and placed on the returned `Task`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). If your code ignores the `Task` returned by an `async` method, then it will not observe those exceptions. Most tasks should be `await`ed at some point to observe their results (including exceptions).

The easiest solution is to make your `Main` asynchronous:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    await ProcessAsync(null);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
```