# Why I couldn't catch the exception in async function that has void return type?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   try {
      var a = MyMethodAsync();
      a.Wait();  // calling Wait throw an AggregateException 
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("Catch");
   }

   Console.ReadLine();
}

static async Task<String> MyMethodAsync() {    
   String s = await TestThrowException();    
   return s;
}

static Task<String> TestThrowException() {
   return Task.Run(() => {
      throw new DivideByZeroException();
      return "placeholder";   // return statement is needed for the compilier to work correctly
   });
}
```

The code above works, the catch block in Main method can catch the `AggregateException` exception (originate from `TestThrowException` and get converted into `AggregateException`).

But if I have the code like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
   try {
      MyMethodAsync(); 
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("Catch");
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
}

static async void MyMethodAsync() {
   await TestThrowException();
}

static Task<String> TestThrowException() {
   return Task.Run(() => {
      throw new DivideByZeroException();
      return "placeholder";   
}
```

then the catch block in Main method cannot catch any exception, why is that?

Comment: Calling `MyMethodAsync(); ` just starts the task but does not wait for it. So when the exception is raised, your program already has left the try...catch. That's why you should in general avoid `async void`.

Comment: because of the Wait() call. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-void-method

Comment: @Bobbey the `Wait` isn't the key bit here

Comment: @KlausGütter thanks for your answer. But even I put `Thread.Sleep(1000);` right below `MyMethodAsync(); ` to make the program stay in try catch, it still can't catch any exception.

Comment: It actually is not a matter of timing, but of communication. Without a `Task` object, there is just no way for your task to communicate to the caller that an exception occurred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you have `async void`, you're basically breaking the ability to correctly signal completion *and* failure; the *only* way it can report failure is if the exception happens *immediately and before any incomplete `await`* - i.e. synchronously. In your case, the `Task.Run` guarantees that this is *not* synchronous, hence any knowledge of the outcome and failure: is lost.

Fundamentally, **never write `async void`** (unless you absolutely have to, for example in an event-handler). In addition to the problem above, it *also* has known complications with some `SynchronizationContext` implementations (in particular the legacy ASP.NET one), which means *simply invoking an `async void` method is enough to crash your application* (at least hypothetically; the sync-context caveat applies more to library authors than application authors, since library authors don't get to choose the application execution environment).

Remove the `async void`. If you want to return "nothing", then you should use `async Task` or `async ValueTask` as the signature:

```cs
static async Task MyMethodAsync() {
   await TestThrowException();
}
```

(which could perhaps also be simplified to)

```cs
static Task MyMethodAsync()
    => TestThrowException();
```

and:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args) {
   try {
      await MyMethodAsync(); 
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      Console.WriteLine("Catch");
   }
   Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: "if the exception happens... synchronously" - That's the behavior from an early CTP. It was changed in a later CTP. Now all exceptions in an `async` method are handled consistently regardless of whether they're thrown before or after an `await`.

Comment: @StephenCleary yeah, I tend to think about it more from the perspective of the caller than the callee - and the caller's side, they don't know the callee's implementation details, and an awaitable callee can throw in the "old" way trivially (mostly: by not being `async`) - but yes: if we restrict ourselves to `async` methods, you're right (let's assume we don't do anything exotic like custom async builders, in which case all bets are off anyway!). In any event: "don't use `async void`" holds as the fix :)