# Exception is thrown but try-catch doesn't catch it?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm calling a method to get and parse a JSON from a URL. The code structure is as follows:

```cs
internal static void CheckIfSettingsExists()
{
    settingsContainer.Values["ApplicationXCurrentVersion"] = Controller.GetCurrentVersionAsync();
}
```

and the `GetCurrentVersionAsync()` function:

```cs
internal static async Task<string> GetCurrentVersionAsync()
{
    string temp = null;

    using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        temp = await client.GetStringAsync("https://someurl.cloud.io/api/v4/VersionCheck");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        App.log.Error("Error fetching version check json from API. Exception raised was: " + e.ToString());
        return temp;
    }
    App.log.Info("Successfully got return for VersionCheck");

    if (temp == null)
    {
        return temp;
    }

    dynamic JsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(temp);

    return JsonObj["LatestVersion"].ToString();
}
```

When I was trying to debug what's happening, I saw that after program runs the line `temp = await client.GetStringAsync("https://someurl.cloud.io/api/v4/VersionCheck");` instead of executing the `catch` block, `System.ArgumentException: 'The parameter is incorrect.'` is thrown at the line that is calling the `GetCurrentVersionAsync()` (line 3 in the `CheckIfSettingsExists()`). I don't understand why this is thrown as even if there was an issue with `GetStringAsync()` function, I already have it in `try` block. Can someone shine  a light for me why this is happening?

Comment: have you try to use POST ? because the error is `parameter` i think it requires a parameter `PostStringAsync("/URL", parameter);`

Comment: I think the error is happening in those last two lines, if you move everything in the try block do you still this behaviour?

dynamic JsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(vatisJSON);

    return JsonObj["LatestVersion"].ToString();

Comment: check the last 2 lines

Comment: Did you miss the `await` before `Controller.GetCurrentVersionAsync();`? or is this just a typo?

Comment: Please post the complete exception, including stack trace.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue... @CharlesHan can't believe I missed such a simple thing. Thank you. I'll delete this question now.

Comment: I also wonder why thats the reason, can you explain?

Comment: This post probably gives better explanation than mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383310/catch-an-exception-thrown-by-an-async-void-method

Comment: I think we all made this kinda mistake before. @cptalpdeniz Do you mind if I put this into the answer so it will help others to find it in the future?

Comment: of course, if you think that's the best thing to do, please do so. I'm a learner and would consider myself as newbie in this platform so whatever you think is the best, please do that.